# Get the value of a string literal type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, string-literals

Is it possible to get the value of a string literal type in Typescript?

```
type MyStringLiteral1 = 'ONE'
type MyStringLiteral2 = 'TWO'

type MyStringLiterals = MyStringLiteral1 | MyStringLiteral2

...

<div>
    // how can I get the value of MyStringLiteral1 here?
</div>
```

Comment: I think you’re looking for an enum.

Comment: I could achieve this result with an enum indeed, but I was wondering if it was also possible with string literals.

Comment: What does it mean to "get value of string literal"? Where does type MyStringLiteral1 come from?

Comment: I just mean to be able to write something close to `<div>{MyStringLiteral1}</div>`, and get 'ONE' printed.

Comment: What you need is pure javascript. It has nothing to do with typescript. Type does not exist in runtime

Comment: I'll use string enums then. Thanks